# Is there a way to get ls to print in colour in busybox?

Tags: linux, unix, busybox, maemo

I'm on a nokia n810 device, which uses `busybox` instead of the usual gnu coreutils. Is there a way to get `busybox`'s ls to print in colour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current busybox version for the latest release of Diablo (43-7) is 1.6.1, which as you've seen doesn't include options for colour.

A fully coloured version of ls can be installed on the n810 from [Andrey's repository](http://nitapps.com/).
If you don't wish to install and use this repository you can install [ls-color](http://nitapps.com/dists/chinook/user/binary-armel/color_ls_1.0-1_armel.deb) manually by downloading and using `dpkg -i`.

Then as x3ja says you can create an alias for it, although since Maemo uses Busybox your default shell is sh, so you'll have to put the alias in your `.profile`

```
alias ls='ls.color'
```

Installing bash is also easy if you so wish - bash2 can be installed from the Maemo extras repository, and bash3 is available through the gronmayer link below.

A great resource for finding apps in certain repositories is [gronmayer's site](http://www.gronmayer.com/it/index.php?lang=en), and of course the latest developments from [Maemo Talk](http://talk.maemo.org).

Comment: I wonder why this isn't default.

Comment: Probably the same reason that they strip the man command and any documentation that gets attached  to packagess - free space concern. The n800 and n810 use an almost identical image, but the n800 has much less memory (hence I boot from a 16gb SD card instead of the internal flash). Plus having your ls in colour is a nice feature, but you could get by without it.

Comment: Wouldn't you actually want to put that in a file pointed to by `$ENV` (which you would set in `.profile`)? That seems to be the closest thing to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` in plain `sh(1)`. (POSIX doesn't even have `/etc/profile` or `.profile`, but it seems most shells do -- `dash(1)` for example.)

Answer (score 4):

ls --color doesn't work?

I thought it was supposed to on the more recent versions.

http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

Comment: You're right, but the nokia n810 just has an older version, I guess.

Comment: Works for me in a docker alpine container.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course put something like this in your login scripts (`.bashrc` or similar):

> `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Then when you type `ls`, it will actually run the command `ls --color=auto` and so it will display in colour`*`.

`*` Sorry for the British spelling, but I am British after all :)

Comment: Countries that originally make the language shouldn't have to apologies for spelling words correctly. Just my 2 cents =)

Comment: Thanks for your tuppence worth :). "Sorry" wasn't the correct word perhaps. Maybe I should substitute in "Note".

Comment: The poster's `ls` *cannot* do color, because it's not compiled in. This would be the right solution for a regular `ls`, but not on busybox.

Comment: @sparks: Heck, I'm american and *I* use British spelling fairly often. I'm consequently always annoyed that spellcheckers are unable to cope with a mixture of US and UK spellings. (It's especially annoying when you want to spell check the documentation in an international software project!) Say, maybe that's why Wikipedia has that "be consistant within an article" guideline...